# Is it possible to have two ConnectionStrings with the same name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Can it is possible to have same name with two Connection String in an application with two datasource like or condition.

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=serverName|serverIpAddress;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User=name;Password=Password;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Can any body help me to doing this.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? This sounds like a (mis-)step along the way to achieving some form of task.

Comment: i want to access my database server with two ip ADDresses. When one is down i can switch it to other....

Comment: Are your databases mirrored?

Comment: its Kind of.. like when my server is unavailable than it will take over on another ipaddress...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your two databases are configured with [SQL Server Mirroring](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852.aspx), then you can actually specify a backup server inside the connection string. You can do this with [`Failover Partner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h52hef8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Data Source=Primary_Server;Failover Partner=Secondary_Server; ... other stuff...
```

Then you just have to edit your existing configuration string with both server addresses and the framework will automatically connect to your secondary server if the primary is unavailable.

There's some idiosyncrasies around the usage of `Failover Partner` though (from what I've read, I haven't used it myself), so I'd recommend reading up on it in depth before implementing it.

If your databases aren't mirrored, you're going to have to implement the failover yourself, probably by abstracting the acquisition of the database connection.

Specify two distinct connection strings in your config (primary and secondary), and then implement some sort of Connection String service that returns the appropriate connection string based on your criteria (i.e. test primary, if fails, return secondary, else return primary, or whatever you want).

Keep in mind that there is a possibility that your server could go offline AFTER testing the string but BEFORE using it, but this is a pretty big edge case. Just keep it in mind if you need to maintain functionality in that situation.

Answer (score 6):

It is not possible because ConnectionStrings are maintained in KeyValuePair and with name being the key.

Please let us know why you need such scenario, then we might be able to help you.

Comment: Due to some reason like net problem the sever is not accessible and it is accessible on another IPaddresses. Can it is possible it will automatically switch to other Server ip address.

Comment: You have to write code manually to pickup from the other connectionstring. If it works for you name them as "MyConnStr" and "MyConnStr_BackUp". And read the connection string from Backup when MyConnstr doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

No you can not have two connection string with same name.
So if you can what is result this code:

```
var connectionString=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
```

Connection string store in KeyValuePair object.

> The application can optionally specify the connection name in an
>   application configuration file that provides the required
>   keyword/value connection string values. In this case, you cannot
>   supply them directly in the connection string. The Name keyword is not
>   allowed in a configuration file.
>
> When the Name keyword is not included in the connection string, a
>   non-empty values for Provider keyword is required.
>
> This keyword is mutually exclusive with all the other connection
>   string keywords.